# How can I implement JUnit testing into this program for a binary search?

Tags: java, testing, junit, binary-search

How can I implement JUnit testing into this program for a binary search, i am quite overwhelmed by this task because I am really unfamiliar with JUnit and also I have all these packages and path that you see in code that I need to use.

I have already tried implementing Testing for just a normal Java class made by me but that did not work either, it would be great if someone could also explain me the syntax of some tests for my code.

```
package de.hska.iwi.ads.solution.search;

import java.security.acl.LastOwnerException;

import de.hska.iwi.ads.search.Search;

public class BinarySearch<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Search<E> {


@Override
public int search(E[] a, E key, int lower, int upper) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    this.lower = lower;
    this.upper = upper;

    if(upper > a.length) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    int ret = binarySearch(a, key, lower, upper);

    return returnValue;
}

int lower;
int upper;
int returnValue;



/**
 * 
 * @param a Array, der durchsucht werden soll.
 * @param key Element, nach dem gesucht wird.
 * @param lower untere Grenze des zu durchsuchenden Bereiches.
 * @param upper obere Grenze des zu durchsuchenden Bereiches.
 * @return index der Stelle wo daa Elemnt ist.
 */
private int binarySearch(E[] a, E key, int lower, int upper) {

    if (lower < upper) {

        int middle = (lower / 2) + (upper / 2);
        int tempInt = a[middle].compareTo(key);

        if (tempInt > 0) {

            return binarySearch(a, key, lower, middle - 1);
        }
        if (tempInt < 0) {
            return binarySearch(a, key, middle + 1, upper);
        }

        this.returnValue = middle;
        if (key.equals(a[middle]) && !key.equals(a[middle-1])) {
            return middle;
        } else {
            return binarySearch(a, key, lower, middle-1);
        }
    }

    if (key.equals(a[lower])) {
        this.returnValue = lower;

        int temp = checkForDuplicates(a, key, 0, upper-1);

        return returnValue;
    }

    int temp = key.compareTo(a[this.upper]);
    if(temp > 0) {
        this.returnValue = (this.upper + 1);
        return (this.upper + 1);
    }
    temp = key.compareTo(a[this.lower]);
    if(temp < 0) {
        this.returnValue = this.lower - 1;
        return (this.lower - 1);
    } else {
        this.returnValue = upper + 1;
    }


    return returnValue;

}

int lastIndex;

private int checkForDuplicates(E[] a, E key, int lower, int upper) {

    if (lower < upper) {

        int middle = (lower / 2) + (upper / 2);
        lastIndex = middle;
        int tempInt = a[middle].compareTo(key);

        if (tempInt < 0) {
            return checkForDuplicates(a, key, middle + 1, upper);
        }

        this.returnValue = middle;
        if (key.equals(a[lower])) {
            this.returnValue = lower;
            checkForDuplicates(a, key, 0, middle-1);
            return returnValue;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    if (key.equals(a[lower])) {
        this.returnValue = lower;
        return returnValue;
    } 

    return -1;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to think about it as "verifying the behaviour".
The behaviour you expect from your BinarySearch class is that for a given array A and an element E, that it will return the index of element E in A if E is an element of A, or -1 if it is not.
A very simple first attempt for tests could look like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGeneration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores.class)
class BinarySearchTest {

    private BinarySearch<Integer> integerBinarySearch;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        integerBinarySearch = new BinarySearch<>();
    }

    @Test
    void returns_index_of_searched_element_when_searched_element_is_in_the_beginning_of_array() {
        // given
        Integer[] numbers = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int numberToSearch = 1;

        // when
        int indexOfSearchedNumber = integerBinarySearch.search(numbers, numberToSearch, 0, numbers.length - 1);

        // then
        assertThat(indexOfSearchedNumber).isEqualTo(0);
    }

    @Test
    void returns_index_of_searched_element_when_searched_element_is_in_the_end_of_array() {
        // given
        Integer[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int numberToSearch = 10;

        // when
        int indexOfSearchedNumber = integerBinarySearch.search(numbers, numberToSearch, 0, numbers.length - 1);

        // then
        assertThat(indexOfSearchedNumber).isEqualTo(9);
    }

    @Test
    void returns_index_of_searched_element_when_searched_element_is_in_the_middle_of_array() {
        // given
        Integer[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
        int numberToSearch = 6;

        // when
        int indexOfSearchedNumber = integerBinarySearch.search(numbers, numberToSearch, 0, numbers.length - 1);

        // then
        assertThat(indexOfSearchedNumber).isEqualTo(5);
    }

    @Test
    void returns_minus_one_when_element_is_not_in_array() {
        // given
        Integer[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int numberToSearch = 42;

        // when
        int indexOfSearchedNumber = integerBinarySearch.search(numbers, numberToSearch, 0, numbers.length - 1);

        // then
        assertThat(indexOfSearchedNumber).isEqualTo(-1);
    }
}
```

This will tell you for example that your search implementation is not correctly behaving when the element is not in the array. For this program to compile you need to add the junit5 and assertj dependencies to your program. If you're using a build tool like gradle, the following entries need to be added to the dependency block in build.gradle:

testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'

testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.12.2'